# Viewpager not updating correctly

Tags: android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-spinner

I am creating an application which has an activity which contains viewpager and this viewpager acts as a container for six fragments. The activity also has a spinner which contains 8 items. The thing which I am trying to achieve is that when I select an item from a spinner then fragments inside viewpager should be destroyed and six new fragments should be populated.

I am using a **FragmentStatePagerAdapter** to achieve this.

```
private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager, ArrayList<Fragment> fmList) {
        super(manager);
        pagerFragmentList = fmList;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) { 
        return pagerFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return pagerFragmentList.size();
    }
}
```

This is how I load new data.

```
pagerFragmentList.clear();
pagerFragmentList = newFragmentList;                        
mPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
mPager.setCurrentItem(0);
```

As I told that I have six fragments inside viewpager and 8 items inside spinner so that makes total of 48 fragment classes but thing is that I am only using six xml layout files for my view and I inflate these views inside all my fragments.

First time when fragments are loaded everything works fine but when I select an item from a spinner then the fragment shows me pre-entered values which I entered when first item of spinner was selected.

This is the snapshot of my app

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Im not sure but you can try this way**

```
    private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager, ArrayList<Fragment> fmList) {
        super(manager);
        pagerFragmentList = fmList;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) { 
        return pagerFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return pagerFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void mDatasetChanged(ArrayList<Fragment> mFmList){
            pagerFragmentList = mFmList;
            this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

**And then in your activity**

```
pagerFragmentList.clear();
pagerFragmentList = newFragmentList;                        
mPagerAdapter.mDatasetChanged(pagerFragmentList);
mPager.setCurrentItem(0);
```